# In Meteor not able to call server side function from client in Mobile App(android) working fine in web app

Tags: meteor

In Meteor my app is working fine as webapp, whereas when I made its package for android using command

```
Meteor build ~/Desktop --server=http://appname.meteorapp.com --Debug
```

and then install that package on android then on calling any of server side side function it is giving 404 error saying Meteor Method not found.

My code is 
import/api/MemberData.js

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const Members = new Mongo.Collection('Members');
```

server/ServerMethod.js

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
 Meteor.methods({
   'LoginMember': function(data) {  //my function for which error is showing not exist
    }
 })
})
```

/imports/ui/components/LoginComponent.js

```
 Meteor.call('LoginMember',{'email':email,'password':password},function(err,res){
            if(err){
              $(".OverlayForLoaderDiv").hide();
                alert(err)
            }else{
console.log(res);
   }
 })
```

Comment: Can you confirm correct [connection to your server](http://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html)? Does it work on localhost? (`meteor run android-device`)

Comment: Yes it is connecting to server perfectly. Yes in localhost it is working fine.